# Pass all URL params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I googled this for quite awhile, surprisingly with no results.

How can I pass all the URL params for an incoming request, through a redirect_to?

I don't know which params they're going to be, so it can't just be the normal `:this => that` way

for example, a request comes in for site.com?utm_source=test&utm_content=y&x=y

But I don't know what the keys are going to be

I'd do the following but it includes a lot of other params I don't want to show in the URL after the redirect

`redirect_to :action => :new, :params => params`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the answer is the following (only for GET params)

`redirect_to :action => :new, :params => request.query_parameters`

For POST params only you can use

`redirect_to :action => :new, :params => request.request_parameters`